# Magento2 Fishpig how to get return ACF image url

Tags: magento2, advanced-custom-fields, fishpig

I'm new to magento2. Now I doing wp post inside my magento2 site by using Fishpig. I have ACF installed in my wp, and i wanted to call it.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5OPy.png)

I try to console log my slider ACF, it returns 4 as i got 4 images in the repeater fields inside a post by using $post->getMetaValue("slider") as it stated inside fishpig documentation.

[My ACF fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zm75.png)

Next, I want to loop out the repeater ACF fields and display Images. Image field already set to return URL.

How can i do that? What method to use? Please show me sample code. Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the slider is returning 4, this means ACF isn't working properly. Ensure you have the latest version of the ACF module in Magento and the free Magento WordPress Integration module.